# JavaScript & jQuery parse JSON in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Sorry about asking this, I can't get it to work even with looking at other questions...

I have a JSON output in "json.php", for example:

```
    [
       {"serverid":"1","servername":"Server One"},
       {"serverid":"2","servername":"Server Two"}
    ]
```

I have a script, to grab the data & parse it into a variable

```
var servers;
jQuery.get('json.php', function(data) {
     servers =    JSON.parse(data);
     jQuery('#servers').servers.servername
});
```

I have a div to output the results to:

```
<div id="servers"></div>
```

Whatever I try, I always get some kind of

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'servername' of undefined" error.

I'd also like to look around the results, however I can't even get it to print atm.

Again sorry for another question like this

Comment: What is `jQuery('#servers').servers.servername` supposed to do??? Obviously, there is no `servers` property on jQuery objects.

Comment: Well I think that's where the problem is, I want to be saying get the servername from the parsed data... no idea how to though.

Comment: did u check if data received from server is json array object? In that case you need to iterate though `servers`

Comment: @Alias: There are two servernames in the response data. Which one do you want?

Comment: @Bergi well I'd like both of them to be displayed one after the other, however at the moment I can't get anything to display.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't you mean something like this? the jQuery object (which is a reference to your div) knows nothing about `servername`. Also, you'll need to **iterate** through the array of items in order to get them all:

```
servers = $.parseJSON(data);

$.each(servers, function(index, value) {
    $("#servers").text($("#servers").text() + " " + value.servername);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H2RC2/1/

Comment: `servers` has no `servername` property.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 6):

The error message is all you need.
The `jQuery('#servers')` wrap the #servers div in the jQuery object. And this object has got no property such as `servers`.

Rather you could use:

```
    var servers = JSON.parse(data);
    var res = '';
    for(var i = 0; i<servers.length; i++){
        res = res + '<p>' + servers[i].servername +'</p>';
    }

    $('#servers').append(res);
```

Comment: `servers` has no `servername` property.